# Rust Conway's Game of Life: struct Board(Vec<Vec<Cell>>)

Tags: rust, game-of-life

What do you think of using `struct Board(Vec<Vec<Cell>>)`? It's nice that I can attach the `Display` trait, and just print the board.

But on the flip-side, we have things that seem wrong, like:

```rust
fn next_step(b: Board) -> Board {
    let Board(mut board) = b;
    // ...
    Board(board)
}
```

And I couldn't find a way to pass a `Board` (or a reference to one) to `nr_of_neighbors`. Moving the `Vec` out in `next_step` (or similarly when using a mutable reference there), prevented me from doing that. Or am I missing something?

Any additional feedback welcome as well!

- Note: it's a `Vec` instead of an `array` in case I add the feature that the player can choose the board size interactively.
- I know the `as i64` isn't that great. Not sure though what's a nice, practical and concise way of dealing with that though.

#### Complete working code

Should run in any ANSI-compatible terminal.

```rust
use itertools::join;
use std::fmt;
use std::{thread, time};

#[repr(u8)]
#[derive(Clone, Copy, Debug, PartialEq, Eq)]
enum Cell { Aliv, Dead }
impl fmt::Display for Cell {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        match *self {
            Cell::Aliv => write!(f, "x"),
            Cell::Dead => write!(f, " "),
        }
    }
}

struct Board(Vec<Vec<Cell>>);
impl fmt::Display for Board {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        let Board(vec) = self;
        let str = join(vec.into_iter().map(|row| join(row, "|")), "\n");
        write!(f, "{}", str)
    }
}


fn main() {
    let mut board = Board(vec![
        vec![Cell::Aliv, Cell::Aliv, Cell::Aliv, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead],
        vec![Cell::Aliv, Cell::Dead, Cell::Aliv, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead],
        vec![Cell::Aliv, Cell::Aliv, Cell::Aliv, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead],
        vec![Cell::Dead, Cell::Aliv, Cell::Aliv, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead],
        vec![Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead],
        vec![Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead],
        vec![Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead],
        vec![Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead],
        vec![Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead],
        vec![Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead],
    ]);

    loop {
        print!("{esc}[2J{esc}[1;1H", esc = 27 as char); // clear ANSI-compatible terminal
        println!("{}", board);
        board = next_step(board);
        thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_secs(1));
    }
}

fn next_step(b: Board) -> Board {
    let Board(mut board) = b;
    for x in 0..board.len() {
        for y in 0..board[x].len() {
            let n = nr_of_neighbors(&board, x, y);
            let cell = board[x][y];
            if cell == Cell::Aliv && (n == 2 || n == 3) {
                // survives
            } else if cell == Cell::Dead && n == 3 {
                board[x][y] = Cell::Aliv;
            } else {
                board[x][y] = Cell::Dead;
            }
        }
    }
    Board(board)
}

fn nr_of_neighbors(board: &Vec<Vec<Cell>>, current_x: usize, current_y: usize) -> u32 {
    let cur_x = current_x as i64;
    let cur_y = current_y as i64;
    let mut count: u32 = 0;
    for x in cur_x-1..cur_x+2 {
        for y in cur_y-1..cur_y+2 {
            if x >=0 && y >= 0
                    && x < board.len() as i64 && y < board[x as usize].len() as i64
                    && !(x == cur_x && y == cur_y)
                    && board[x as usize][y as usize] == Cell::Aliv {
                count = count + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    count
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### On your notes:

- Problems with `u64`/`u32` got fixed once I started using `usize` everywhere.
- Board shouldn't be copied every time in `next_step`, `&mut Board` could be used instead.
- `next_step`, as well as `nr_of_neighbors` could be a methods.

### Bugs:

- There is a bug in calculating number of neighbors: your condition `!(x == cur_x && y == cur_y)` is equivalent to `x != cur_x || y != cur_y`, which is not intended.
- There is a problem with your algorithm: it depends on the order of the iteration, when you should really apply changes to the new board.

### Notes about the code below

- You are using `newtype` pattern to implement traits that you need on the type that doesn't do it itself. I advise you to look into `derive_more` crate. Basically, I derived a `Deref` implementation in order not to write it myself. That way, everywhere where &Board is used, it can be coerced to &Vec> so you don't have to write `self.0[x]` to access a row.

### Resulting code

```
use std::fmt;
use std::{thread, time};

use itertools::join;
use itertools::Itertools;

use derive_more::Deref;

#[repr(u8)]
#[derive(Clone, Copy, Debug, PartialEq, Eq)]
enum Cell {
    Alive,
    Dead,
}

impl fmt::Display for Cell {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        match *self {
            Cell::Alive => write!(f, "x"),
            Cell::Dead => write!(f, " "),
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Deref)]
struct Board(Vec<Vec<Cell>>);

impl Board {
    fn nr_of_neighbors(&self, cur_x: usize, cur_y: usize) -> usize {
        let x_min = cur_x.saturating_sub(1);
        let y_min = cur_y.saturating_sub(1);

        let x_max = (cur_x + 2).min(self.len() - 1);
        let y_max = (cur_y + 2).min(self.len() - 1);

        (x_min..x_max)
            .cartesian_product(y_min..y_max)
            .filter(|&(x, y)| x != cur_x && y != cur_y && self[x][y] == Cell::Alive)
            .count()
    }

    fn next_step(&mut self) {
        let mut new_board = self.clone();

        for x in 0..self.len() {
            for y in 0..self[x].len() {
                let n = self.nr_of_neighbors(x, y);
                let cell = self[x][y];

                if cell == Cell::Alive && (n == 2 || n == 3) {
                    // survives
                } else if cell == Cell::Dead && n == 3 {
                    new_board[x][y] = Cell::Alive;
                } else {
                    new_board[x][y] = Cell::Dead;
                }
            }
        }

        self.0 = new_board;
    }
}

impl fmt::Display for Board {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{}", join(self.iter().map(|row| join(row, "|")), "\n"))
    }
}

fn main() {
    #[rustfmt::skip]
        let mut board = Board(vec![
            vec![Cell::Alive, Cell::Alive, Cell::Alive, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead],
            vec![Cell::Alive, Cell::Dead,  Cell::Alive, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead],
            vec![Cell::Alive, Cell::Alive, Cell::Alive, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead],
            vec![Cell::Dead,  Cell::Alive, Cell::Alive, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead],
            vec![Cell::Dead,  Cell::Dead,  Cell::Dead,  Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead],
            vec![Cell::Dead,  Cell::Dead,  Cell::Dead,  Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead],
            vec![Cell::Dead,  Cell::Dead,  Cell::Dead,  Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead],
            vec![Cell::Dead,  Cell::Dead,  Cell::Dead,  Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead],
            vec![Cell::Dead,  Cell::Dead,  Cell::Dead,  Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead],
            vec![Cell::Dead,  Cell::Dead,  Cell::Dead,  Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead, Cell::Dead],
        ]);

    loop {
        print!("{esc}[2J{esc}[1;1H", esc = 27 as char); // clear ANSI-compatible terminal
        println!("{}\n", board);
        board.next_step();
        thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_secs(1));
    }
}
```

Comment: very cool thanks! I didn't know about `saturating_sub` and `derive_more` of course... hm.. but you still have to copy the whole board `new_board = self.clone();` which doesn't seem very efficient? or is it some lazy cloning? couldn't find what clone does for Vec in the docs...

Comment: @mb21, that's not about efficiency, but correctness of algorithm - you can't mutate the board you are currently working on. I believe there is a dynamic programming solution, but I'm not sure. There could be 2 Vecs inside the Board, so that you don't reallocate every iteration and at the end of `next_step` you just make a swap. Or a cell can contain two states - current and future, which will improve data locality. If you care about efficiency I recommend using Vec<Cell> instead of Vec<Vec<Cell>>, so that there's no extra indirection.

Comment: Ah, of course. Can't believe I missed that... have been working too much with immutable structures (in other langs). One last question: is using methods instead of functions generally favoured in Rust? or is it more of a stylistic choice, where OOP people use methods and functional people use functions?

Comment: @mb21 I think it's a choice, but I'm learning rust just like you.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, you should only put a `Vec` inside of a `Vec` if the inner `Vec` will have a dynamic size. Otherwise, you lose a lot of performance due to indirection (you have a pointer to an array of pointers, which points to each row), which screws with the CPU cache. Instead, you should use a single `Vec` which has a size of `width * height`. This pattern is so common that there's a crate to do just that—[ndarray](https://docs.rs/ndarray/0.13.0/ndarray/macro.array.html) (see also [this](https://docs.rs/ndarray/0.13.0/ndarray/struct.ArrayBase.html#indexing-and-dimension)). However, you could also write your own wrapper functions that multiply the column by the width and add the height.

> is using methods instead of functions generally favoured in Rust? or is it more of a stylistic choice, where OOP people use methods and functional people use functions?

It really depends. When using the newtype pattern (which you are), absolutely use methods—it's the most ergonomic option. However, using free functions is a great idea when working with other types where it doesn't make sense to have a struct. You should think of structs as data, not logic. Using a struct to hold data and using functions to operate on that data is great. However, using a struct to hold logic generally means that you should rethink your layout. That's not always the case, but is a good start.